# The folder size of folder Logs\CBS is increasing forever

Tags: updates, window

My disk driver on my computer is increasing unexpectedly. I have to reset my computer but it didn't resolve the issue. After my inspection, I found the folder `C:\Windows\Logs\CBS` is too big.
[image]
I tried to delete them manually but I got this error
[image]

I believe the issue comes from Window Update so I disable it from Administrator Tool/Service.

But again, the issue was resolved. The file's size is still bigger and bigger. You can see the file size now is now 47Gb. (before it was 41Gb)

[image]

Anyone also faced this issue and know how to fix it can help me?

Thank you.

UPDATE 1: I used Process Explorer (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) to find and kill the process TiWorker.exe but I didn't success

[image]

Comment: TiWorker is part of TrustedInstaller; though has been known to be hijacked. Run a malware scan. You can delete the older cbs logs if you are struggling for space, until you figure it out, & the cbs.log itself will regenerate as needed, once you've fixed the issue.